# How to create a function that classifies and returns classified values

Tags: r, function

I am trying to look at `data(movies)` that are in `library(ggplot2movies)`, and I am trying to calculate total number of movies in `random-year` that are classified to `n` genres.

For instance, if `n=2`, it means I am counting those movies which are classified in two genres. A movie X could be a Comedy and Romance. Then this movie X would be counted using this function below.

For instance, I might be looking at:

`movies_released_2000 = data.frame(movies$year==2000)`

What I did was:

```
nums_movies <- function(input_df, n) {
 counts = lapply(input_df,rowSums)
 if (counts == n){
break}
}
```

Hoping to return:

```
nums_movies(movies_released_2000[18:24],3)
# [1] 5 # five movies released in 2000 were classified into three genres at the same time
```

What I did was to use `lapply` to calculate row sums of each movie and then only return those who's row sum equals n.

But this gives me a problem with

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

What I was hoping to calculate was the total number of movies that have been classified to n-number of genres. For instance, if I type `nums_movies(movies_released_2000[18:24],3)`, it would give me an integer that calculates how many movies released in 2000 were classified in three different genres(e.g. it could be movies classified into "Comedy","Romance", "Thriller").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses the reshape2 library and melt() method to turn the data frame into a so-called molten format that reshapes the genres as column names to genres as rows along with the 0 or 1 flag of being in the genre.  plry library then aggregates these and returns all values for all years, which are then easily sub-set by the year of interest (or may be put into a function to pass the year as an argument)

library(ggplot2movies)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

```
data(movies)

movies <- movies[,c("year","Action","Animation","Comedy","Drama","Documentary","Romance","Short")]

movies <- melt(movies,"year",variable.name="genre",value.name="in_genre")
movies_by_genre_year <- ddply(movies,.(year,genre),summarise,total=sum(in_genre))

movies_by_genre_year[movies_by_genre_year$year==2000,]
```

So for the example year of 2000, the following genres count the following number of movies:

```
    year       genre total
750 2000      Action   154
751 2000   Animation    89
752 2000      Comedy   561
753 2000       Drama   793
754 2000 Documentary   175
755 2000     Romance   207
756 2000       Short   449
```

Per comment, an additional answer using base R

```
data(movies)
movies <- as.data.frame(movies[,c("year","Action","Animation","Comedy","Drama","Documentary","Romance","Short")])
year <- 2000
movies<-lapply(movies[movies$year==year,c(2:7)],sum)
data.frame(year=year,m)
```

Update showing count of movies counted in number of n-specified genres:

```
data(movies)
movies <- as.data.frame(movies[,c("year","Action","Animation","Comedy","Drama","Documentary","Romance","Short")])
year <- 2000
n <- 3
matches <- apply(movies[movies$year==year,c(2:7)],1,function(x) { sum(x)==n })
data.frame(year=year,n=n,multi_genres_count=sum(matches))
```

Here, in year 2000, 58 movies were listed in 3 different genres

```
  year n multi_genres_count
1 2000 3                 58
```

Comment: I am trying to use only base r tools, instead of using other packages. Also, the result gives total of each genre, I was more looking to find those classified in n-different genres.

Comment: Updated solution using base R.  I'm not clear what's meant by n-different genres.  Perhaps you could update your original question to specify using base-R functions only and also giving an example of expected output?

Comment: There are movies that are classified as both "Romantic" and "Comedy". That means, they are classified into 2 different genres. That's what I mean by `n`-different genres.

Comment: Added an additional update to count n-different genres